# Why isn't toString() always automatically invoked

Tags: java, android, android-adapterview

So why isn't toString always invoked? This is an example using the Android API.

E.g

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
        int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(this, adapterView, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Will not compile. However if I change it to

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
            int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(this, adapterView.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

It will. What is the actual difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you mean by always? `toString()` is just a method which returns a `String` representation of the object. The `Toast.makeText` expects a `String` parameter, but in the first case you give an object of the `AdapterView` class. So it won't compile:)

Comment: Thanks. I usually use System.err to debug my code, and forgot it is capable of handling more than just strings. :)

Answer (score 8):

`adapterView` isn't a `String`.

`toString()` isn't invoked automatically by the compiler to perform a cast - that would undermine type safety a little. Only when there's a `+""` for example, the compiler will call toString() automatically.

Answer (score 6):

The only situation in which toString() is inserted by the compiler is in string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

also, this

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
            int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "" + adapterView, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

will compile ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Android API, but AdapterView is not actually a subclass of CharSequence so you have to apply toString().

Answer (score 0):

I suppose Toast.makeTest's second parameter is of type String.  Then trying to pass a parameter of type AdapterView won't work.  toString() is never automatically called, except when concatenating Strings (""+adapterView would work as well, but is more ugly).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler decides which method is required from the name of the method and the number and types of each argument supplied. In your first example, it looks for a method called makeText which has an AdapterView as its second parameter, and finds none (your compile error would have told you that.  In your second example the second parameter is a String and the compiler finds the matching method.
Note that the compiler can't find the method first, then make the parameters fit, else we couldn't have overloaded methods.